# jquery slider fancy box shows hover arrows. but copy on my site lacks arrows when hovering

Tags: jquery, slider, google-chrome-console

On my website I am trying a few jquery sliders. I go and find a nice slider example on jqueryscript.net, copy it but often they do not work and I really do not understand why. 
If you can point me toward a solution that would be great.
Also if you think there are much better ways than jquery,please let me know.

Now here is a good example:
Jquery fancy box demo is here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Lightbox-With-Amazing-CSS3-Effects-Fancy-Box-2/demo/

When you click on an image of the " simple image gallery" the lightbox that opens has arrows when you hover over it.

I have copied this demo to my website here: https://www.hanscees.com/slider/fancy2/fancy2.html
If you do the same here, there are no arrows.

My firefox/webdeveloper tools / console shows no errors.

Why are the arrows not showing up?
I have made sure all css and js are in folders and subfolders like in the original html source.

Here is the firefox console
[image]
(no errors.)

But chrome console does show the culprit[image]

So missing images...... (how embarrasing)

Comment: `"My firefox/webdeveloper tools / console shows no errors."` The console shows 4 errors (404 errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Just open chrome's console and you will see the missing files:

```
https://www.hanscees.com/slider/fancy2/hccss/helpers/blank.gif
https://www.hanscees.com/slider/fancy2/hccss/helpers/fancybox_loading.gif
https://www.hanscees.com/slider/fancy2/hccss/helpers/fancybox_sprite.png
https://www.hanscees.com/slider/fancy2/hccss/helpers/fancybox_overlay.png
https://www.hanscees.com/slider/fancy2/fancybox_overlay.png
```

Upload these files to right path and it will work

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the chrome console shows more than the firefox console

Comment: @Hans-Cees So you can mark my answer as your solution

Comment: sorry, didnt know how to do that. Was just too obvious .